# If statement doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: php

I may be doing it wrong but take a peek. If I hardcode the logic, it works but not if I try to use it as a variable.

```
if($range <= 50) {
    $operator = "<=";
} else {
    $operator = ">=";
}

foreach($cursor as $s) {
    $data = round($this->distance($zip_lat, $zip_lon, $s["lat"],$s["lon"]), 2);

    if ($data .$operator. $range) {
        $zipcodes[] = "$s[zipcode]";   
    }
}
```

I mean, I could add the if/else inside the foreach but wasn't sure if it adds any "overhead."

Comment: Shouldn't it be operator = ">" for the else part?

Comment: Others have already solved your problem, but not exactly explained the problem. The reason your code doesn't work is that $data . $operator . $range evaluates to a string, not a boolean expression like you're using it, and a non-empty, non-zero string always evaluates to true.

Comment: lol @ title: I think `most` languages will surely have ensured that the 'if' statement functions properly ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
if ($range <= 50 ? $data <= $range : $data >= $range) {

}
```

or use an eval()

Comment: perfect, that seems to work. So lets say I added the additional "if/else" from the beginning of my code into the foreach loop, would that add "overhead?"

Comment: @luckytaxi, don't worry about the overhead of an additional IF in PHP, the whole thing is bloat anyway and wont make 0.00001% difference to your running time!

Comment: Why are you so worried about "overhead" ? Is this a known bottleneck (seriously, i think you are optimising prematurely)?

Comment: yep you could use an if/else as well, no diff in terms of speed

Comment: Not really. If you read from a  file or do a db lookup anywhere in your code, it will take 1000's of times longer than adding the if. Point being don't worry about such a minuscule optimization unless you are running this block in 100,000 iterations.

Comment: @ChristopheD, calm down, I'm just asking a question. Thanks for playing.

Comment: @Byron - possibly. It's pulling from a "table" with 42,000 rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if ($data .$operator. $range)
```

Is always true, because it is a string ,not a null.

You can find out problem using this simple code:

```
$data="0";
$operator=">=";
$range="1";

if ($data .$operator. $range) {
       echo   $data .$operator. $range . " is true !";   
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the 'always' part, consider: `$data = '0'; $operator = ''; $range = ''; if ($data .$operator. $range){ echo 'this statement is always true'; };`

Answer (score 1):

The 'dots' only do regular 'string' concatenation - you can't expect them (injected as strings) to behave like regular, 'real' operators.

Think about it: if `$data = 'data1'` and `$range = 50` your if statement becomes:

`if ('data1<=50')` which will probably just evaluate to true or false, just as `if ('yournamehere')` or `if('randommumbojumbo')`

Comment: right, but since in my case both $data and $range are numeric figures, I thought I could throw the "operator" into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

I very much suspect that the if is simply evaluating the string $date.$operator.$range (which will always return true), as all you're doing is concatenating the operator and operands together.

As such, you may need to [eval](http://www.php.net/eval) (duck and cover people, duck and cover) the contents of the if.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it does as defined by the concatenation operator. No need to suspect anything ;) +1 for duck and cover

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a closing }

Comment: hah, yea just caught that. thanks. i do have it in my code though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to do this:

```
foreach ( $cursor as $s ) {
    $data = round($this->distance($zip_lat, $zip_lon, $s["lat"],$s["lon"]), 2);
    if ( $range <= 50 ) {
      if ( $data <= $range ) {
          $zipcodes[] = "$s[zipcode]";   
      }
    } else {
      if ( $data >= $range ) {
          $zipcodes[] = "$s[zipcode]";   
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a variable representing an evaluation operator.  You would have to switch your code to something like:

```
foreach ($cursor as $s) {
    $data = round($this->distance($zip_lat, $zip_lon, $s["lat"],$s["lon"]), 2);
    if ($range <= 50 && $data <= $range) {
        $zipcodes[] = $s['zipcode'];
    } else if ($data >= $range) {
        $zipcodes[] = $s['zipcode'];
    }
}
```